# Choose several elements sequentially in a list for round robin scheduling

Tags: python, numpy

In `Python`, there is `itertools.cycle()` to choose an element sequentially one by one. However, how to choose several elements at once sequentially for round robin? For example, I have

`list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`

Instead of one by one, I want to choose two elements at once, e.g., `'a','b'`, then `'c','d'`, then `'e','f'`, then `'a','b'`, and so on, for each iteration.

How to do that in Python or Numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recycle the `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle

def cycles(iterable, n = 2):
    it = cycle(iterable)
    while True:
        yield [next(it) for _ in range(n)]

it = cycles(list("abcdef"))
for _ in range(4):
    print(next(it))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b']
['c', 'd']
['e', 'f']
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Is ```it = cycle(iterable)``` should be ```it = itertools.cycle(iterable)```?

Comment: @tfreak Sorry I've missed `import` part :P

Comment: If you want the `cycles` to return hashables, change the last line of list comprehension to `tuple(next(it) for _ in range(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the solution:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
i = 0
pairs = list()
while i < len(l) - 1:
    pairs.append([l[i],l[i+1]])
    i += 2
if i == len(l) - 1: 
    pairs.append([l[-1]])
print(pairs)  # prints [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

If l is `[1,2,3]`, the code will print `[[1,2],[3]]`

Note, that `list` is bad name for variable, you are overriding python `list` type constructor this way: `list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`

Answer (score 1):

Since `cycle` iterates forever you can get away with just chunking the output with the chunking recipe from the itertools standard documentation.

```
import itertools

def grouper(n, iterable):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args)

def round_robin(L):
    return grouper(2, itertools.cycle(L))
```

Comment: Is possible to do like this? ```for i in range (1, 10): print(round-robin(L))``` such that for each ```i```, I can print two elements?

Comment: `for i, t in zip(range(1, 10), round_robin(L)): print(t)`. Or, since you're using itertools anyway, `for t in itertools.islice(round_robin(L), 10): print(t)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `numpy` - just `.reshape(...)` it:

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools

lst = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])

for el in itertools.cycle(lst.reshape(-1,2)):
    print(el)
```

`.reshape(-1,2)` essentially reshapes your list to have `2` columns, and proportional number of rows (`originalLength/2`).